# Can VSTS use Local server? Not Cloud

Tags: tfs, localhost, azure-devops, local, localserver

we hope using just **local** server not **cloud** on **VSTS**

can we use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, VSTS (Service) itself is a Cloud-based service. VSTS comes by default with some **hosted agents**,

[image]

Those hosted agented are given by Microsoft itself, where don't need to maintain/configure the server agent by yourself.

However, If you really want your own dedicated agent for build/release, you can install that by following this [tutorial](https://www.benday.com/2018/01/11/howto-install-tfs2018-vsts-build-agent-on-windows-server-core/)

[image]

[image]